# Оформление вопросов вида "Почините сайт блабла.ру"

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, тематика

Кто подписан на метки html, css, js тем безусловно попадались подобные вопросы:

"Есть сайт [http://блабла.ру](http://%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%83) и там сломалась вёрстка, при `*вставить условие*`. Как починить?"

И с такими вопросами нужно что-то делать, ибо они плохи в таком виде, так как:

1. Пользователю не предоставлен кусок кода, для того чтобы ознакомиться с проблемой, лишь ссылка на сайт.
2. Как только проблема будет устранена:

   1. В вопросе останется ссылка, рекламирующая этот сайт.
   2. Воспроизвести проблему будет невозможно, так как кода в вопросе не было.

Итог: в таком виде вопрос превращается в мусор.

**Решение проблемы**

Требовать:

1. Наличие кода.
2. При необходимости снимки экрана, где эта проблема себя проявляет.
3. ... ?

Comment: Пример такого вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497635/182771

Comment: Предложение изменить адрес в заголовке, например, на мойсайт.рф или mysite.ru , как на нейтральную, не несущую какой-либо эмоциональной составляющей формулировку. Спасибо.

Comment: > В вопросе останется ссылка, рекламирующая этот сайт. — Разве на Stack Overflow как в Википедии ссылкам на внешние сайты не присваивается `nofollow`? Спасибо.

Comment: @edem да, думаю. Там обсуждается чуть более общая проблема, и имеющийся там ответ куда подробнее и полезнее.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5468/Слишком-умный-дубликaт

Comment: @alexolut не все знают значение иностранного слова "дубликат", пояснение не помешает.

Comment: @edem оно иностранное? О_о

Comment: @alexolut да, от лат. duplicatus - удвоенный.

Comment: @edem смешно :)

Comment: @alexolut ну, не думаю, что словари пишут юмористы, хотя кто его знает.

Comment: Я к тому, что куча слов заимствовано из других языков. Но утверждать, что "дубликат" это иностранное слово... В современном мире это выглядит несколько странно.

Comment: @alexolut может быть, но это уже обсуждение не по теме вопроса.

Answer (score 17):

Такой вопрос - попытка нахаляву разместить заказ на фриланс. Как правило, он сопровождается невнятной формулировкой проблемы. В доброй половине таких вопросов автор, получив решение, уйдёт и даже не примет ответ.

Поэтому я за жесткие меры по отношению к таким вопросам:

1. Сразу закрывать с формулировкой "В вопросе нет кода, воспроизводящего проблему".
2. Не давать ответов даже в комментариях.
3. <s>Ставить минусы</s> Хотя бы написать предупредительный комментарий тем, кто всё-таки даёт ответы, тем самым поддерживая автора вопроса, который поленился задать нормальный вопрос.

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: тактические минусы? :)

Comment: @Grundy больше минусов богу минусов! Жги вопросы лентяев и тех, кто им сочувствует! =)

Comment: @Grundy это не тактические, а воспитательные.

Comment: кстати у таких размещальщиков есть отговорка по коду: типа его так много и тут не получается выложить :)

Comment: @Grundy ок. "Я написал вам ответ, но там много кода, и я не могу его выложить.".

Comment: @NickVolynkin, на самом деле, авторы _ответов_ ничем не провинились и не вполне заслуживают минус за _качественный_ ответ. Собственно система голосования предназначена для оценки контента а не действий пользователя.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вот это спорно. Их ответ будет иметь гораздо меньше смысла, как только сайт перестанет работать или на нем изменится код. Неясно будет, какая проблема решалась.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, все что вы перечислили это проблемы _вопроса_ а не ответа. Это примерно тоже самое, что заранее минусовать ответы, которые _могут_ перестать соответствовать вопросу после его существенной правки ТС.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ок, уговорили на правку )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кстати под одним из вопросов я уже видел подобный комментарий :-D!

Answer (score 13):

Для таких вопросов есть специальная причина закрытия:

> Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Ну и если вопрос в текущем виде не несет пользы сообществу в целом -- можно смело ставить минус.

**UPD:**

Я категорически не согласен с предложением **@NickVolynkin** минусовать *хорошие* ответы на подобные вопросы. Система голосования на SO нужна для оценки *контента* (вопросов/ответов) а не *действий* пользователей. Если кто-то может и хочет помочь автору-лентяю -- это его право.