# Слишком умный [дубликaт]

Tags: поддержка, предложение, локализация, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

На текущий момент перевод англоязычной причины закрытия "duplicate of..." [выглядит так](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264408?key=a09b386a03fda6b8b4d90dee515b3e5a):

> этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение…

Зачем здесь это своеволие, которое к тому же [вводит людей в заблуждение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5463/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B#comment20560_5463)?

Предлагаю не мудрствовать лукаво, а перевести его дословно:

> дубликат...

Возможные вариации:

> дубликат вопроса...

> дубликат другого вопроса...

Comment: но ведь иногда не дает отметить будликатом, если нет ответа

Comment: @Grundy по-моему, это правило не распространяется на Мету. Ну и проблема всё же именно в довешивание лишнего смысла в перевод. Мне такой подход не очень нравится.

Comment: _по-моему, это правило не распространяется на Мету_ - а этот вопрос только по мете или вообще?

Comment: @Grundy строки едины и для Меты, и для основного сайта.

Comment: Да там надо всё посокращать.

Comment: @Qwertiy плнст пддрж!

Comment: не стоит закрывать вопрос как дубликат, если другой вопрос не содержит одобренного ответа (движок на основном сайте это запрещает). Цель дубликатов -- в одном месте ответы собирать, а не формально DRY принцип поддерживать. Использование конкретной фразы, а не жаргона, специфичного для сайта, является более предпочтительным.

Comment: @jfs если бы Ваш комментарий был написан как ответ, я бы минусанул.

Comment: @alexolut *"я бы минусанул"* малоинформативно. Заметили вы фактически неточное утверждение в моём комментарии? Какое? Просто с чем-то не согласны? С чем именно? Постарайтесь понять, что эти формулировки не от балды пишутся (почитайте обсуждения на английской Мете). Если вы хотите их изменить, то чтобы не ухудшать сайт (bit rot), явно укажите чём сейчас плохо и как ваше предложение может улучшить сайт и какие у вас (если  есть) доказательства.

Comment: @jfs объём Ваших комментариев вполне подходит для ответа. Минус за несогласие. Озвученная Вами цель - собрать ответы в одном месте - не может быть обеспечена, т.к. имеющиеся ответы не переносятся при закрытии как "дубликат". Держать несколько одинаковых вопросов открытыми смысла нет даже если ответов ещё не опубликовано. При появлении ответа на одном из вопросов, другой (дубликат) будет уже сложно найти, поэтому делать это имеет смысл сразу. В любой случае, текущий вопрос о правилах перевода eng-rus, а не о внесении нового или изменении старого поведения.

Comment: @alexolut  основная разница между вопросом и комментарием вовсе не в объёме, а в тематике (поэтому я опубликовал комментарий а не ответ. Посмотрите на первое и последнее предложения в вашем комментарии), движок может усиливать наличие одобренного ответа у вопроса-дубликата (это не случайность), слияние веток может быть, но автоматического слияния всех вопросов-дубликатов нет (ответы должны идеально совпадать), нельзя добавлять новых ответов к вопросу закрытому как дубликат, но они не удаляются (вехи для поисковика — возможно автоматическое перенаправление посетителей)...

Comment: ...[продолжение] Это служит очередным доказательством, что не следует жаргон специальный использовать в описании типа слово "дубликат" (механику работы которого даже опытные участники по разному могут понимать) а следует использовать формулировки, которые  могут быть проверены каждым для себя (есть решение по ссылке текущего вопроса или нет). Для меня акцент любого слова, функциональности на сайте, прежде всего в том как это служит людям, использующим сайт, а не то какое формальное правило можно к вопросу/ответу применить.

Comment: Вот как раз сейчас столкнулся с дубликатами и тоже пришёл почитать что в таких случаях делать. Дубликаты: https://parg.co/8e9 и https://parg.co/8ey . И, кстати, эти оба два поста имеют одну и ту-же share ссылку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1016239/14955 - Они уже отмечены как дубликаты?